# Dropdown list fed in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, reactjs, laravel

I take over someone's job and find out their code.

It's a mix of reactjs and jQuery.

The goal is to look for information in the database and insert it in a drop-down list.

With Google Chrome, the drop-down list is fed

[image]

but not with Firefox :

[image]

With Chrome's console (console.log($("[name='liste_horaire']").length);)

I see 1 and 0 with Firefox

Here is the reactjs code (which I found)

```
    var layout = {};
      return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["Container"], null, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["Container"], null, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("h2", null, "2020-2021 2\xE8me quadrimestre 31/03/2020 MA Bloc 1")), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
        className: "form-group row"
      }, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("label", {
        className: "col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"
      }, "Liste des horaires"), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
        className: "col-md-6"
      }, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("select", {
        onChange: this.handleChange,
        type: "text",
        className: "form-control selectpicker",
        name: "liste_horaire"
      }, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("option", {
        value: "test",
        defaultValue: true
      }, "1"), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("option", {
        value: "test2"
      }, "2")))), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["Container"], {
        className: "custom-home-table"
      }, /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["Button"], {
        onClick: this.onAddItem
      }, "Ajouter un evenement"), /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(ResponsiveReactGridLayout, _extends({
        onBreakpointChange: this.onBreakpointChange
      }, this.props, {
        /*  layout={layout}
          onLayoutChange={( layout) =>
              this.onLayoutChange(layout)
          }*/
        onDragStop: this.onDragStop,
        onResizeStop: this.onResizeStop
      }), daysLayout.map(function (item) {
        return createDayElement(item);
      }), layout1.map(function (item) {
        return createStaticElement(item);
      }), lodash__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.map(this.state.items, function (el) {
        return _this2.createElement(el);
      }))));
    }
  }]);
```

and the jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'getAllHoraires',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function success(data) {
    
    //  console.log('getAllHoraires:');
    //  console.log(data);
    
    console.log($("[name='liste_horaire']").length);

    $("[name='liste_horaire']").empty(); //je vide la ld avant de la remplir, autrement doublon
    
    $.each(data, function (idx, value) //parcours du retour php quie est au format json
    {
      //ajoute le id et le nom de l'horaire à la liste deroulante
      $("[name='liste_horaire']").append($('<option/>').val(value.id).html(value.name + ' ' + value.id));
      console.log(value.idx);
      console.log(value.name);
    }); //fin du each
  },
  error: function error(_error) {
    alert("dans erreur ajax get liste horaire ");
    console.log(_error);
  }
}); //https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/test-hook.jsx
//https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.jsx
//we use external class and function
//call external function makeLayout with as argument the class AddRemoveLayout

Object(_makeLayout__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["makeLayout"])(_AddRemoveLayout__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["AddRemoveLayout"]); //getHoraire
```

as well as the PHP code (Laravel 7) :

```
public function getAllHoraires()
    {
        $horaires = Horaire::get();
       /* $quadrimestres = Quadrimestre::latest()->get();
        $years = Year::latest()->get();*/

        return response()->json($horaires);
    }
```

Could you please tell me how I can solve this problem and at the same time improve the code?

Comment: Different results in different browsers won't have anything to do with the backend (php/Laravel). The issue must be with jQuery/React. When you compare page sources in both browsers, do you see any differences?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I see in firefox's console about the combobox : name:"" and for Chrome, I see name: "liste_horaire"

Comment: That would explain the jQuery not firing, since it's relying on the name to fetch the element. Meaning the error originates from React not rendering the element properly. Unfortunately, it's difficult for me to tell what could be going wrong (try to poke around with some console logging), but at least we've narrowed down the problem.

Comment: Yes thank you El_Vanja for your help.  I think react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("select", {
        onChange: this.handleChange,
        type: "text",
        className: "form-control selectpicker",
        name: "liste_horaire" is the problem...  I still searching for the solution...

Comment: For information, I tried with Safari, Opera and Chrome, all are working.  Only Firefox is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

Before, I called my Object **after** the Ajax, now, I call it **before** and it works :

makeLayout(AddRemoveLayout);

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'getAllHoraires',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
```

Hope it will help others...